# How can you check if the bot is being pinged?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I am creating a command that "kills" people. I want the bot to return the message "Ha! You thought! @Author died!" if they ping the bot. (How do I get the Bot to see if it is pinged?) ***Answer has been updated and now fully works.***

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

module.exports = {
    name: 'kill',
    description: 'kills',
    execute(message, args, bot) {
      message.delete({ timeout: 30000 });
  
      if (message.content.startsWith('-kill')) {
        const target = message.mentions.users.first();
        const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
  
        if (message.mentions.has(bot.user)) {
          return message.channel.send(`HA! SIKE! <@${message.author.id}> died.`);
        }
        message.channel.send(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> has died!`);
        console.log(`<@${memberTarget.user.id} died.`);
      }
    },
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `message.mentions.has(bot.user)` to check if the bot is mentioned. Also, make sure you're passing the bot to your `execute()` method instead of instantiate a new one:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'kill',
  description: 'kills',
  execute(message, args, bot) {
    message.delete({ timeout: 30000 });

    if (message.content.startsWith('!kill')) {
      const target = message.mentions.users.first();
      const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);

      if (message.mentions.has(bot.user)) {
        return message.channel.send(`HA! SIKE! <@${message.author.id}> died.`);
      }
      message.channel.send(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> has died!`);
      console.log(`<@${memberTarget.user.id} died.`);
    }
  },
};
```

And in your main JS file pass down the `bot` object:

```js
// ...
client.commands.get('kill').execute(message, args, bot) 
// ...
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Okay, now it's not doing anything. It just deletes my message and never replies. I don't think it can get past the if - return statement to actually send a message and when I ping it, it doesn't send the return message and just ends. (My bot doesn't crash though and there aren't any errors.)

Comment: Thank you, though I use client instead of bot. :)